# Add striped effect to own events in Calendar.app

Tags: macos, catalina, calendar

Sometimes I see events like these on external calendars shown in my Calendar.app:

[image]

There is a striped pattern behind it. Makes it look cancelled.

How do I add this effect to events that I create myself?

Answer (score 2):

That is how Calendar indicates that you have responded with a 'Maybe' to the meeting invite. There isn't a way that you can create your own meeting and respond to yourself with a maybe. However, you could create a separate calendar account and send yourself (original calendar) invites, to which you respond 'Maybe'.

Comment: Good answer, thanks for explaining it. I wish that Calendar.app let you apply this graphical effect manually. How do you "send yourself invites"?

Comment: made slight edits: I am suggesting creating an additional calendar account, and send an invite to the original calendar, where you indicate 'maybe' (two calendar accounts needed)